# XML validation using XSD in postgres procedure

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

DB - Postgres

I need to perform XSD validation for an XML present in a table, Consider I have two tables, TableA with 2 columns[ id, xmldata] and TableB with 2 columns[id , xsd] now how to validate the XML present in the TableA with  a XSD from TableB in a postgres procedure. Any comments on this will will be very helpful.